Using "user_tags" when posting story via graph.instagram throws error
Posting a story via graph.instagram.com works fine - but as soon as I add the parameter "user_tags" I get an error:
{
"error": {
"message": "An unknown error has occurred.",
"type": "OAuthException",
"code": 1,
"fbtrace_id": "AdG69JJokToh-pumknfZ..."
}
}
This is what my request looks like:
https://graph.instagram.com/v21.0//media?access_token=xxx&media_type=STORIES&image_url=xxx&user_tags=[{username:'ersom'}]
The same request works perfectly with "type=IMAGE".
Any ideas?
